# Stripe createPaymentMethod function not doing anything

Tags: javascript, .net, stripe-payments

I'm implementing the stripe payment Intents on a .NET Application following this guide https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web-manual#collect-payment-method and trying to "collect card details with the function **createPaymentMethod** as shown in Step 1.
I straight copied the code in my aspx page.

The HTML one:

```
<input id="cardholder-name" type="text">
<!-- placeholder for Elements -->
<div id="card-element"></div>
<button id="card-button">Submit Payment</button>
```

and the JS one:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

var elements = stripe.elements();
var cardElement = elements.create('card');
cardElement.mount('#card-element');



cardButton.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardNumber, {
        billing_details: {
            name: 'Test Name',
        },
    }).then(function (result) {
        alert(result); //CODE GETS HERE ONLY IF RESULT IS ERROR (ex. wrong card number)
        // Handle result.error or result.paymentMethod
    });
});
```

The problem is that on the click function, the code enters inside ".then(function (result)" only in case of errors (ex. "Wrong card number" and so on...). While if i put correct data it will never enter. I checked on the various browser consoles and there isn't any error.
Am i missing something?

**FIXED**

I'll write here for someone that may have the same problem.
The problem was that the card elements disappeared from the DOM before the promise was resolved.
To fix this, just add `ev.preventDefault()` inside the on click listener